# How to create an array from a Obj in another array? JS React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, filter

I want to build a self updating filter with checkboxes.

My Data:

```js
const Shooting= [
    {
      name: "John & Johna ",
      tag: ["wedding", "couple"],
      img: [ src1 , src2, ...] //irrelevant
    },
    {
      name: "Mario & Marie",
      tag: ["couple", "NSFW"],
      img: [ src1 , src2, ...] //irrelevant
    },
  ];
  export default Shooting;
```

how my output should look like that:

```
Filter:
[]wedding 
[]couple  
[]NSFW    
// [] are checkboxes, "couple" is a duplicate in the array
```

My code idea:

1. Get all tags into a new array
2. Build function to remove duplicates from new array
3. list the filtered array with map-function -> Obj.map((tag))=>{...}

My question:

How can I get all tags in a new list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `[...new Set(Shooting.map(({ tag }) => tag).flat(1))]`,

-> `Shooting.map(({tag}) => tag)` will give back the tags in array.

-> Then we can use [array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to concatenate the tags.

-> Then to remove duplicate, we use `...new Set(...)` .

```js
const App = () => {
  const Shooting = [
    {
      name: "John & Johna ",
      tag: ["wedding", "couple"],
      img: ["src1", "src2"]
    },
    {
      name: "Mario & Marie",
      tag: ["couple", "NSFW"],
      img: ["src1", "src2"]
    }
  ];

  const result = [...new Set(Shooting.map(({ tag }) => tag).flat(1))];


  return <div> 
    <h2> Filter: </h2> 
    <ul>
      {
        result.map((list, i) => <div key={i}><input type="checkbox" /> {list} </div> )
      }
    </ul> 
   </div>
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App  />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `reduce` function  with `set`

```js
const Shooting= [
    {
      name: "John & Johna ",
      tag: ["wedding", "couple"], 
    },
    {
      name: "Mario & Marie",
      tag: ["couple", "NSFW"], 
    },
  ];
  
 const result = Shooting.reduce((acc, item) => {
   return [ ...new Set([...acc, ...item.tag]) ]
 }, [])
 
 
 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reducer to get all unique tags

```js
const array = [
  {
    name: "name1",
    tag: ["tag1", "tag2"],
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    tag: ["tag2", "tag3"],
  },
];

const tags = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item.tag.forEach((tag) => {
    if (!acc.includes(tag)) {
      acc.push(tag);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Then with your tags you can do whatever you want. Good luck!